# Select() blocking on stdin, will not time out

Tags: c, networking, nonblocking

I am writing a program which receives UDP messages as well as takes input from users however my STDIN is still blocking with select. When I FD_CLR the stdin fd before select the program runs fine, indicating that the stdin socket is always ready to have  data read from it. I tried introducing a timeval tv to time it out but this doesnt appear to be working either. Should I be closing the socket somewhere or calling FD_CLR where I am not?
The end result should be a non blocking STDIN but currently it blocks. 
Thank You

```
int
wait_for_input(){
            fd_set fds;
            int maxfd, sd, err, n;
            struct sockaddr_in addr;
            char stdbuf[BUFLEN];
            unsigned char udpbuf[BUFLEN];

            //memset(stdbuf,0x0,sizeof(stdbuf));
            memset(stdbuf,0x0,sizeof(udpbuf));

            sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

            if(sd<0) {
            printf("Failed to Open UDP socket");
            }

            addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
            addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
            addr.sin_port = htons(host_list[0]->port);
            err = bind(sd,(struct sockaddr *) &addr,sizeof(addr));

            if(err < 0){
                            printf("ERROR: Cant bind port");

            }

                            struct timeval tv;
            while(1){
                            FD_ZERO(&fds);
                            FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO,&fds);
                            FD_SET(sd,&fds);
                            tv.tv_sec = 1;
                            tv.tv_usec = 0;
                            fflush(stdout);
                            select(sd+1,&fds,NULL,NULL,&tv);

                            // If a UDP message arrives
                            if(FD_ISSET(sd,&fds)){
                                            n = recv(sd,udpbuf,sizeof(udpbuf),0);
                                            unpack(udpbuf);
                                            recompute_my_dv();
                                            fflush(stdout);

                             }
                            //If console data is entered.
                                if(FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds)){
                                            fgets(stdbuf,sizeof(stdbuf),stdin);
                                            parse(stdbuf);
                                            printf("server> ");
                                            fflush(stdout);
                                            FD_CLR(STDIN_FILENO,&fds);


                             }

                     }



 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried checking what the `select` call returns?

Comment: You do know that `STDIN` is line-buffered?

Comment: @SergeyL - Line-buffering is done at the library or terminal level, not down at the POSIX layer. It is possible to read stdin in an unbuffered manner.

Comment: Some ideas: post a complete program that compiles and shows the issue (what you posted works fine for me but I'm guessing at the rest of the program).  Also, if you have strace, run the program under strace and you'll immediately see how select is working/not working.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. As soon as a UDP message arrives select returns -1. However I am certain that the UDP data is arriving because I can see it in the program. It looks like there is no data in STDIN until there is a return of -1 meaning an error and it looks like its trying to send it to the STDIN FD. thanks

Comment: Have you considered `print`ing `errno` in your debugger?

Comment: -1 indicates error.  Check out the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FD_ISSET doesn't return 1 (or true) if you have a message on that socket's buffer, it returns true if the given file descriptor is part of the file descriptor set. That's one problem.

The next is that your loop should start (the while loop that is) should begin before the select statment and loop back to that. You should capture the value returned by the select.  This is because select returns how many bits are in the buffer you specified in argument 2 of select (read, write, or error).  So if you specified read as the buffer, you will want to read how ever many bits was returned by select.

I think those are the 2 main problems.  Hope this helps.